# Show that the group operation of conjugation is compatible with the bilinear form $\langle A,B\rangle=1/2 \textrm{ trace }AB$

Tags: lie-algebras, group-homomorphism, orthogonal-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices, general-linear-group

Question 6.6 of General linear groups (Artin Algebra):

> (a) Show that $O_2$ operates by conjugation on its Lie Algebra
>
> (b) Show that this operation is compatible with the bilinear form $\langle A, B\rangle = 1/2 \textrm{ trace }AB. $
>
> (c) Use the operation to define a homomorphism $O_2 \rightarrow O_2$, and describe this homomorphism explicitly.

(a) The Lie Algebra of $O_2$ is $2\times 2$ skew-symmetric matrices and hence we have to show that given $P\in O_2$ and $Q$ a skew-symmetric matrix, $P^{-1}QP$ is skew-symmetric and that the operation is associative; both are easy to verify.

(b) I do not understand what "compatible" means. My first instinct is that to show $\langle A, B\rangle=\langle P^{-1}AP, P^{-1}BP\rangle$.

(c) I do not see how one can define an homomorphism from $O_2$ to itself with the knowledge of (a) and (b)

I request you to help me with (b) and (c). Please provide **hints** in place of answers wherever possible. Thank you

Comment: For (b), I would think your instinct is right. Can you show that?

Comment: @torsten we can use the fact that trace $CD$ $=$ trace $DC$ to show trace $P^{-1}ABP$ $=$ trace $AB$

Comment: In (c), is the homomorphism required: $f:O_2 \rightarrow O_2$, $f(A) =P^{-1}AP$, where $P\in O_2$?? But $f$ depends on $P$, so there is some sort of ambiguity.

Comment: This above is from the 2nd edition; this is ex 8.6.8 in the 1xt edition.   I assume working over reals.  The issue is the homomorphism really seems to be $O_2 \longrightarrow O_1$.  You can verify this abstractly since the 2x2 real skew symmetric matrices live in a 1-d vector space (i.e. each is identified with exactly one point on the 'imaginary line'), or by calculation:for $P\in SO_2(\mathbb R)$  then $P$ commutes with any matrix in its Lie algebra, so conjugation acts like $1$, and if P has determinant -1, it is a reflection (and calculation shows) it acts like $-1$.

Comment: It may be prudent to table this problem and try the 3 final miscellaneous problems in the chapter, covering Killing forms, etc. more generally.

Answer (score 0):

for **(c)**

I think the homomorphism should have been Lie$(O_2)→$Lie$(O_2)$

$O_2$ just give the action of conjugation, so $P^{T}=P^{-1}, P\in{O_2}$

we know that Lie$(O_2)$ is skew-symmetric matrix space, and for $A\in$Lie$(O_2)$,  $(PAP^{-1})^{T}=PA^{T}P^{T}=-PAP^{T}$

so $PAP^{T}\in$Lie$(O_2)$

and it's easy to know that $A\leadsto{PAP^{-1}}$ is a homomorphism

I don't know whether it's true

Comment: when can I get 50 scores to leave a comment?